# Does the copy code to clipboard option exist in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

does the button to copy to cliboard exist with R markdown?

It exists in **Quarto** (with the `code-copy` option) [image]

and with **pkgdown** websites
[image]
but is it possible to add it to a R markdown or R notebook document?

Comment: Doesn't look like it unless it's been added very recently but suggests [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/copy-to-clipboard-buttons-for-code-blocks/45367/5) to use `bookdown::html_document2()` instead to get this feature.

Comment: Is it possible to include this feature when the output is a beamer presentation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the package [`klippy`](https://github.com/RLesur/klippy) to insert a copy to clipboard button in Rmarkdown HTML documents. To only thing you need to do is add this code somewhere in your document:

````
```{r klippy, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE}
klippy::klippy()
```
````

To install the package, you can use the following code:

```
remotes::install_github("rlesur/klippy")
library(klippy)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Copy code to clipboard"
date: "2022-10-31"
output: html_document
---

```{r klippy, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE}
klippy::klippy()
```

Some example code:

```{r}
# Summary of mtcars dataset:
summary(mtcars)
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see a copy to clipboard button in the top left of the code chunk.

---

For more information check the [documentation](https://rlesur.github.io/klippy/articles/klippy.html).