# Copy code to clipboard when R Markdown output is a beamer presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer

I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73138448/does-the-copy-code-to-clipboard-option-exist-in-r-markdown/74266886#74266886) that there is a way to copy code to clipboard in R Markdown when the output is set to `html`. Would it be possible to do so when the output is a beamer presentation?

Comment: Did you try :   ```{r, highlight=TRUE, clipboard=TRUE}
# Your code here .... ```
 options in the `knitr` chunk options to achieve this?